# i want write a sql query to fetch data between two tags in soap xml which present in the clob column of a oracle table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, soap, clob

```
xml which is present ina clob column of xml_message table : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oag="http://gateway.consumerhub.commercial.volvocars.net/oagis" xmlns:oag1="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <oag:UpdateConsumerAndOpportunityData_v1 xmlns:ns3="http://www.ford.com/oagis">
            <oag1:ApplicationArea>
                <oag1:Sender>
                    <oag1:LogicalId>Volvo</oag1:LogicalId>
                    <oag1:Component>Vista</oag1:Component>
                    <oag1:Task>SyncConsumer</oag1:Task>
                    <oag1:AuthorizationId>AUTH-SK034</oag1:AuthorizationId>
                </oag1:Sender>
                <oag1:CreationDateTime>2016-01-27T15:07:47Z</oag1:CreationDateTime>
                <oag1:BODId>sk-connect-034</oag1:BODId>
            </oag1:ApplicationArea>
            <oag:DataArea>
                <oag1:Sync confirm="Always">
                    <oag1:SyncCriteria expressionLanguage="XPath">
                        <oag1:SyncExpression action="change"/>
                    </oag1:SyncCriteria>
                </oag1:Sync>
                <oag:Consumer>
                    <oag:Header>
                        <oag:Source>AU</oag:Source>
                    </oag:Header>
                    <oag:ConsumerDetails Category="Person">
                        <oag:ConsumerId/>
                        <oag:Language>EN</oag:Language>
                        <oag:PersonDetails>
                            <oag:FirstName>firstname_email_034</oag:FirstName>
                            <oag:Surname>sname_email_034</oag:Surname>
                        </oag:PersonDetails>
                        <oag:EmailAddress Active="true">ticc888@yahoo.com</oag:EmailAddress>
                        <oag:EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Business">ahng2@hotmail.com</oag:EmailAddress>
                        <oag:EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Invoice">jsmith@gmail.com</oag:EmailAddress>
                    </oag:ConsumerDetails>
                </oag:Consumer>
            </oag:DataArea>
        </oag:UpdateConsumerAndOpportunityData_v1>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now i want all the email address from this xml to fetch and insert into another table.
this xml contain 3 email address ,i want till n number of email address to be fetched that a xml file will contain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Data out of XML from a column in ORACLE database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687285/select-data-out-of-xml-from-a-column-in-oracle-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the linked answer shows, you can use XMLTable to extract multiple values; but you need to define at least the namespaces you use, and construct the XPath properly. So to get just the email addresses you can do:

```
select x.emailaddress
from xml_message m
cross apply xmltable (
  xmlnamespaces (
      'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soapenv",
      'http://gateway.consumerhub.commercial.volvocars.net/oagis' as "oag",
      'http://www.openapplications.org/oagis' as "oag1",
      'http://www.ford.com/oagis' as "ns3"
  ),
  'soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/oag:UpdateConsumerAndOpportunityData_v1/oag:DataArea/oag:Consumer/oag:ConsumerDetails/oag:EmailAddress'
  passing xmltype(m.xml_clob)
  columns
    EmailAddress varchar2(64) path '.'
) x;
```

| EMAILADDRESS |
| --- |
| ticc888@yahoo.com |
| ahng2@hotmail.com |
| jsmith@gmail.com |

The XPath doesn't refer to oag1 or ns3 but it doesn't hurt to include them anyway, and you might need them to extract other information from the same XML document.

This also lets you extract multiple values at once; or to filter base on an attribute - you might, for example, only want to include the email addresses with attribute Active set to true, which you can do by adding that condition to the XPath:

```
  'soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/oag:UpdateConsumerAndOpportunityData_v1/oag:DataArea/oag:Consumer/oag:ConsumerDetails/oag:EmailAddress[@Active="true"]'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7dd255e2dc9425c22a298df4c104dd9b)

You can read more about manipulating XML [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-4805CF1C-A00D-4B88-AF2E-00A9DB6F3392).

Comment: Also what if i want to fetch contact number as well within the same xml :   <oag:ContactNumber Type="Telephone" Usage="Mobile">9898989898</oag:ContactNumber>
                        <oag:ContactNumber Type="Telephone" Usage="Home">756565</oag:ContactNumber>
                        <oag:ContactNumber Type="Telephone" Usage="Business">212121</oag:ContactNumber>
                        <oag:ContactNumber Type="Telephone" Usage="Invoice">414141</oag:ContactNumber>

Comment: @AshwiniJoshi - just change the XPath and column clauses to the node you want; [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=64fb487788688aab69de7b38222b9333). Getting both in one query is trickier as there is no obvious correlation between the two pieces of data - if usage is unique then you could align some with that, but you'd have to figure out how to deal with non-matches, and duplicates if they are allowed (e.g. two mobile numbers).